# Python class showing "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, class, oop, positional-argument

**I was making a python class in which it has an employee's name, salary, and the number of leaves as attributes and was trying to show the final salary of an employee deducting the salary for the days he/she has not come but it is showing an error. The error is:**

```
    TypeError: Employee.f_salary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I had written the code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, no_of_leaves):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.no_of_leaves = no_of_leaves

    def f_salary(self):
        self.f_salary1 = self.salary - 500 * int(self.no_of_leaves)

    def display(self):
        print(f"Employee's name: {self.name}\nEmployee's monthly salary: 
        {self.salary}\nNo.of leaves that employee has taken: {self.no_of_leaves}")

nol = input("No. of leaves the employee has taken: ")

john_smith = Employee('John Smith', 182500, nol)

Employee.f_salary()
Employee.display()
```

Comment: `Employee.f_salary` and `Employee.display` are just *functions*, not methods that already have an instance of `Employee` bound to the `self` parameter of the underly function.

Comment: How do you expect ``Employee.f_salary()`` to "know" it has to compute the salary for John Smith?

Comment: Suppose you had two instances of `Employee`: how do you think `Employee.f_salary()`, for example, would know whose salary to print?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the method on the instance not the class object.

```
john_smith.f_salary()
john_smith.display()
```

Because the `self` parameter is a reference to the class instance which called the method in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you call the method on the class instead of the object you created.

```py
Employee.f_salary()
Employee.display()
```

This can be easily fixed by using the object name.

```py
john_smith.f_salary()
john_smith.display()
```

You can however pass self explicitly though if you use the class to call a method.

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        # Etc.

some_foo = Foo()

# These are more or less equivalent if we assume no class extends Foo
Foo.bar(some_foo)
some_foo.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks! it was a very silly mistake and I am still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods are just class attributes. `Employee.f_salary` is a reference to a function that requires a single argument.

`john_smith.f_salary`, though, is more interesting. Because `function` objects implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), accessing the value as an attribute of something always triggers its `__get__` method, so that

```
Employee.f_salary == Employee.__dict__['f_salary'].__get__(None, Employee)
john_smith.f_salary == Employee.__dict__['f_salary'].__get__(john_smith, Employee)
```

In the first case, `__get__` simply returns the function itself, so when you try to call it, it still expects an argument for its `self` parameter.

In the second case, `__get__` returns an instance of the `method` class, which internally keeps two references: one to `john_smith`, and one to the function itself.

When you try to call the `method` object, it simply takes its own arguments and passes them, along with `john_smith`, to the underlying function.

As such, `john_smith.f_salary()` returns the value of `Employee.f_salary(john_smith)`.